# Use cell value as worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to VBA, and i have something i dont understand now.

I've been trying to copy Worksheets by only copying Cells with a specific colour in a cell below.
I want to be able to change the worksheet using the same cells by typing in the worksheet name also in a cell below.

I already tried using CONCAT (WsName,rCell) but that didnt really work.

Here is what i also tried:

```
Function ColorReplicate(rColor As Range, WsName As String, rCell As Range)
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
Dim ws As Worksheet

lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set ws = ws.Sheets(WsName)

If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
    vResult = ws.rCell
End If

ColorReplicate = vResult
End Function
```

I would really apreciate help.

*Edit 09.05.2022*

**Example**

=ColorReplicate($A$37;B2;C37)

=ColorReplicate(Cell with searched Colour; Set Cell to look foe in other ws; Cell with ws name in it)

If there are better ways to copy a worksheet this way i would love to hear so

Many thanks

Comment: `vResult = ws.Range(rCell.Address)`, my guess.

Comment: @BigBen didnt work ;/ should address be a String or smt different?

Comment: What specifically didn't work?

Comment: @BigBen i used `rCell = ws.Range(rCell.WsName)` at the beginning so it would read the correct cell, but that doesnt seem to work because the function gives out "'#VALUE!"

Comment: `rCell` has no `.WsName` property, so it's a bit unclear what you're actually trying to do.